# PDF files content not included in the indexing of Content Sources of Windows Search Server 2008

Tags: search

The PDF files were crawled by FoxIT PDF iFilter 3.0, but PDF files content is not included in the indexing of Content Sources of Windows Search Server 2008. No crawl log error.

Comment: I would talk to FoxIT. It is very likely that their latest version is not compatible with that old version of the Search Server.

Comment: Hi Matthew,  please suggest any solution.  Thanks.

Comment: The solution is to contact FoxIt tech support and ask them if they support the old search server with their new product. Failing that you could use SharePoint 2013 as it does not require an iFilter. 2013 indexes PDFs natively.